# Scroll linear layout with listviews xamarin android

Tags: android, layout, scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/firstLV"/>

<ListView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/secondLV"/>

<Button 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="button"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have simple linear layout with two listviews and one button inside ScrollView.
I need to scroll linear layout. But now i watch full first list view and scrolled second listview. And I can't watch my button.
Code for fill listviews:

```
 ListView firstListView = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.firstLV);
        ListView secondListView =   (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.secondLV);
        string[] dataList = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, dataList);
        firstListView.Adapter = adapter;
        secondListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

How can I scroll exactly linear layout?
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here has to do with how Android reacts with a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. It is not recommended for a user to have these actions together because the device has trouble recognizing which views to scroll and the `ScrollView` will intercept touches from the `ListView`. The real solution would be to combine everything into one `ListView` (or even better potentially a `RecyclerView` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)). Two `ListViews` are really unnecessary and with a custom adapter can be done in one. Then, the `ScrollView` also becomes obsolete.